# PHP - подсчитать сумму конкретных элементов в многомерном массиве

Tags: php

Столкнулся с не стандартной задачей. В корзине интернет-магазина Opencart 3 товары приходят обычным массивом. Первая задача была отсортировать их по производителям и выделить название производителя на верхний уровень массива, чтобы получилась группа и подгруппа.

```
Имя производителя
Товар 1
Товар 2
Товар 3
```

Эта задача была решена так:

```
usort($data['products'], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['manufacturer'] <=> $b['manufacturer'];
});

$res = [];
foreach ($data['products'] as $x) {
   $res[$x['manufacturer']][] = $x;
}
```

Далее стоит вторая задача. Вывести название группы товаров (Это имя производителя) и сумму этих товаров, чтобы выглядело так:

```
Имя магазина 1 - 343$
Имя магазина 2 - 678$
...
```

Для этого вношу изменения в предыдущий код.

```
$res = [];
foreach ($data['products'] as $x) {
   $res[$x['manufacturer']][] = $x['price'];
}
```

И получаю такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [Bykilian] => Array
        (
            [0] => 179.00 $
            [1] => 80.00 $
            [2] => 108.00 $
        )

    [Kidsnail] => Array
        (
            [0] => 194.00 $
        )

    [Longstormaier] => Array
        (
            [0] => 199.00 $
            [1] => 150.00 $
            [2] => 84.00 $
        )

)
```

Теперь нужно как то посчитать сумму в каждой группе и вывести ее во фронт энд. На этом этапе встрял. У кого то будут идеи?

Comment: 1. Что вам мешает в переборе приплюсовывать значения и по окончанию выводить эту сумму? 2. Можно посчитать с помощью JS если скажем сумма сразу не видна и должна показываться после события клика по элементу к примеру. 3. Как можно подсказать если вы не показываете фронтенд какой сейчас и что вы хотите чтобы было, гадать сидеть как я выше???

Comment: Тут нужен чистый PHP. Я в тексте указал, как хочу чтобы было во фронтэнде: Название магазина - общая сумма товаров(Bykilian - 456$) например. Сложить это все мне мешает то, что не знаю как правильно обратится к значению этого массива и как правильно foreach составить.

Comment: Вы когда перебираете все изделия вносите в массив с ключем Имя производителя это изделие что вам мешает в нем создать массив скажем `products` и туда вносить эти изделия а в соседнем массиве `sum_products` в котором изначально будет 0 вы просто делаете что-то типа `$res[$x['manufacturer']]['sum_products] = $res[$x['manufacturer']]['sum_products] + $x['price']` это в случае если нет символа $, который вы также можете пропустить с помощью регулярки если нужно

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал на вашем примере. Все работает, только ошибка крутится: Notice: Undefined index: sum_products. Как можно от нее избавиться?

Comment: Лучше используйте код что я в ответе указал, и засчитайте пожалуйста ответ если он вам помог, спасибо, будут вопросы, пишите. Ошибки не должно быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете подсчитывать сумму изделий при добавлении (если цена является лишь числом, без символа $):

```html
$res = [];
foreach ($data['products'] as $x) {
   $res[$x['manufacturer']]['products'][] = $x['price'];
   $res[$x['manufacturer']]['products_sum'] = (isset($res[$x['manufacturer']]['products_sum'])) ? $res[$x['manufacturer']]['products_sum'] + $x['price'] : $x['price'];
}
```

В таком случае, массив получится следующего вида:

```html
Array
(
    [Bykilian] => Array
        (
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 179.00
                    [1] => 80.00
                    [2] => 108.00
                )
            [products_sum] => 367.00
        )
)
```

З.Ы. Если вы храните цены с символом $, вы можете перед сложением используя регулярные выражения взять только число чтобы php сделал сложение, в таком случае при выводе в бэкэнд вам придется дописывать знак $.

Comment: Работает отлично. Я уже адаптировал его под все остальные задачи, которые стояли на этой странице. Спасибо большое за помощь. Единственное что int добавил, а то ругался он. (int)$x['price'] сделал.